# Add jpeg image file in Qt using C++

Tags: c++, qt

I am a beginner with regards to Qt. I need code to browse an image which is stored in system and add the selected image file (jpeg only) during run time.

Comment: This question is very unclear. You need to clarify what you want to achieve. And in general asking for code is not appropriate on SO. We can help you when you have a clear question, but won't do your work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [QFileDialog::getOpenFileName()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName) for getting a file path to open.

EDIT

The second part of your question is not clear. There are a variety of ways to display an image in Qt. You have to be more specific.

Comment: sorry,here am trying to browse and upload image from my local system which is in the format JPEG only.How do i do this operation in qt?

Comment: Upload to what? Over what protocol? If you want more help, be more specific.

Comment: hey thanx donotalo now its working..but i need some more help that how to display directory path after selecting image?here my code is  QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
                                                    tr("Open image"), QDir::currentPath(),tr("Image jpeg format only(*.jpeg)"));

Comment: One way is to use messagebox: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmessagebox.html#information